# rails cancan allow users to edit *only* their data, but view everyones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan

I have a rails app that uses Devise and cancan. I am wanting to allow only users to edit **their own** data, but still be able to view everyone elses.

I have:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.role == "member"
    their own only
    can :read, User
    can :manage, User, user_id: user.id
  elsif user.role == "guest"

    can :read, User
  end
```

I also have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :name , :email # Include default devise modules. Others available are:

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

ROLES = %w[member guest]


  def is?( requested_role )
    self.role == requested_role.to_s
  end

end
```

But I can still edit and delete other users comments. When I shouldn't be able to. Why? What am I doing wrong? 
Rails 4
Devise 2.5.2
cancan 1.6

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying `user_id` as a column name for your User model:

```
can :manage, User, user_id: user.id
```

I'm willing to bet that User has no `user_id` column -- it only has an `id` column. What you want is this:

```
can :manage, User, id: user.id
```

Double check this by looking at your `schema.rb` file and making sure that there is (or is not) a `user_id` column. The actual ID column is called `id` and is not listed in `schema.rb` but is actually present in the database table.

Also, be sure that you really want to allow `:manage` permissions. The `:manage` symbol is very powerful and allows the user to do anything with the object in question, including deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

For giving the permission of user to edit their own data, change

From

```
can :manage, User, user_id: user.id
```

To

```
can :update, User
```